# pop-up code for android

Tags: android, android-layout

i want a pop-up to display one of d string data present in a database in random or in a sequence. what code should i b using for this kind of a pop-up. am very new to android development. i would appreciate help. please don't leave this unanswered.

```
package popupTest.popupTest;

import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class popupTest extends Activity {

 PopupWindow popUp;
 LinearLayout layout;
 TextView tv;
 LayoutParams params;
 LinearLayout mainLayout;
 Button but;
 boolean click = true;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
  layout = new LinearLayout(this);
  mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  tv = new TextView(this);
  but = new Button(this);
  but.setText("Click Me");



  params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  tv.setText("Hi this is a sample text for popup window");
  layout.addView(tv, params);
  popUp.setContentView(layout);
  // popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
  mainLayout.addView(but, params);
  setContentView(mainLayout);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
             popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
        }

      }, 1000);
  //Use this to dismiss as per your need...
    // popUp.dismiss();

 }
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         popUp.dismiss();
        return false;

    }
}
```

will this code help me?

Comment: use Toast - easiest. Toast.makeText(COntext, "text", Toast.length).show();

Comment: What happened when you tried that code?

Comment: i have a number of entries in my database. at a specific time of a day, say 14hours, i want the first tuple in the table to be displayed as a popup.

Answer (score 0):

A Toast is the easiest for this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-toast-example/

Answer (score 0):

For poping up some information, there are two most commonly used methods.

- Toast
- AlertDialog

**Toast:**

it appears for a specific amount of time, displays some info and then disappears.

**Dialog:**

It displays your message but doesn't goes away from screen untill the user presses a button for example "Ok" button.

**For toast:**

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your message here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**For Dialog:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

 alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

 alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("This is to notify you");

 alertDialogBuilder.show();
 alertDialogBuilder.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                    {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```